# how to create word2vec for phrases and then calculate cosine similarity

Tags: python, word2vec, cosine-similarity, phrase

I have just started using word2vec and I have no idea how to create vectors (using word2vec) of two different set of documents, document1 contain set of words plus phrases(list of lists)and document2 contain only phrases.both lists have different length.

For example :

```
document_list1 =[['blogs', 'vmware', 'server', 'virtual', 'oracle update', 'virtualization', 'application server','infrastructure', 'management']['team',olympics,'sport','win''chinese olympic']..]
document_list2 = ['microsoft visual studio','desktop virtualization',
'microsoft exchange server','cloud computing','windows server 2008']['demonstration sport','commonwealth games','summer olympic games']..]
```

how i can calculate  cosine similarity? should i create vectors for all the sentences in document_list1 and then for document_list2 and then cosine similarity or i should create vectors separately for each sentence in both document_lists?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to treat `document_list1` and `document_list2` as separate documents and calculate the cosine similarity between them?

Comment: Are you trying to implement word2vec by yourself? Or are you using any particular package? If so, have you followed any tutorials of a word2vec package?

Comment: @akilat90 i want to treat doument_list1 and document_list2 separately. for example calculate vectors for both separately and then cosine similarity.and then get the most matched word from document_list2 with document_list1. for example for document_list1 i got phrase from document_list2 "desktop virtualization" with the highest cosine simiarity

Comment: @Taegyung no i want to use gensim word2vec

Comment: There are quite good beginner's tutorials for gensim word2vec over the web: http://kavita-ganesan.com/gensim-word2vec-tutorial-starter-code/ https://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/

Comment: @Taegyung i already read this tutorial.my question is not about basic word2vec. its about how i can create vectors for two different sets both are list of lists and then cosine similarity between them